# NO PATH ! error and questions to gradient_path.cpp in global_planner

Tags: ros, navigation, global-planner, move-base, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

  #### **Problem Description:**

I am trying to get a global path based on a 500 * 500 static map with **global_planner** (indigo). I set up the parameter *use_grid_path* to be *false*, so that the path is calculated with a gradient descent method. Goal Pose is fed with the 2D Nav Goal in Rviz. Sometime it works fine by showing the global path. But sometimes it publishes rosconsole [Error] messages repetitively in the terminal, even if a potential map is successfully showed by Rviz.

```
[ERROR] [1444812100.339654309, 6406.380000000]: NO PATH!
[ERROR] [1444812100.340210027, 6406.380000000]: Failed to get a plan from potential when a legal potential was found. This shouldn't happen.
[ERROR] [1444812100.364187125, 6406.410000000]: NO PATH!
[ERROR] [1444812100.364835403, 6406.410000000]: Failed to get a plan from potential when a legal potential was found. This shouldn't happen.
```

I dug a little bit into the code in **gradient_path.cpp** http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/global_planner/html/gradient__path_8cpp_source.html#l00068. I think it must failed at row 80 to get this kind of error message.

```
00080     while (c++ 
But my static map is not big, and I have already got the potential map. So I do not really understand what is going on here.
Question to the code in gradient_path.cpp 
http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/global_planner/html/gradient__path_8cpp_source.html#l00068
1. This part comes from function *float GradientPath::gradCell(float potential, int n)**. In my opinion, the potential from cells on the left, right, up and down side should be taken into account. But at line 285, it is a fixed cell. Why should man always take care at this fixed cell?
00276     // check for in an obstacle
00277     if (cv >= POT_HIGH) {
00278         if (potential[n - 1] 
2. Why do we take stc, stc + 1, stcnx and stcnx + 1 but not other neighbors for interpolation? 
00181             // get grad at four positions near cell
00182             gradCell(potential, stc);
00183             gradCell(potential, stc + 1);
00184             gradCell(potential, stcnx);
00185             gradCell(potential, stcnx + 1);
00186 
00187             // get interpolated gradient
00188             float x1 = (1.0 - dx) * gradx_[stc] + dx * gradx_[stc + 1];
00189             float x2 = (1.0 - dx) * gradx_[stcnx] + dx * gradx_[stcnx + 1];
00190             float x = (1.0 - dy) * x1 + dy * x2; // interpolated x
00191             float y1 = (1.0 - dx) * grady_[stc] + dx * grady_[stc + 1];
00192             float y2 = (1.0 - dx) * grady_[stcnx] + dx * grady_[stcnx + 1];
00193             float y = (1.0 - dy) * y1 + dy * y2; // interpolated y
3. Why do we only consider these two horizontal bounds, why not the vertical bounds? 
00091         if (stc  xs_ * ys_ - xs_) // would be out of bounds
00092         {
00093             printf("[PathCalc] Out of bounds\n");
00094             return false;
00095         }
```

These questions troubled me a lot. Please help ~~

Thanks in advance :-)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219109/no-path-!-error-and-questions-to-gradient_path.cpp-in-global_planner/) by [maomao2015](https://answers.ros.org/users/24481/maomao2015/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-10-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having the same kind of error.

One solution could be to increase the constant distance values in [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/jade-devel/global_planner/src/gradient_path.cpp#L84) from 0.5 to 1.0 .

I think this is due to missing potential values on cells around the start of the path, see this picture [image description http://www2.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/%7Epalmieri/images/example.png](http://www2.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/%7Epalmieri/images/example.png)

The white space under the axes represents cells to which no potential was assigned.
Sometimes the cell (nx,ny) is far more than 0.5 (m?)  from start cell in [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/jade-devel/global_planner/src/gradient_path.cpp#L84), therefore the path extraction will return false (exit from the while loop).

What do you think?

Best,

L.

---

Originally posted by [palmlster](https://answers.ros.org/users/2172/palmlster/) with karma: 28 on 2016-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2018-10-19**:
Replacing 0.5 with 1 seems to work; it actually refers to cells number.

**Comment by [jinseoi](https://answers.ros.org/users/32501/jinseoi/) on 2019-01-26**:
it works for me too, thank very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

These are valid points. As you may know, global_planner is based off of nav_fn, and as a result, some of the bugs propagated forward.

1. This is a valid point. This error came from [nav_fn](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/jade-devel/navfn/src/navfn.cpp#L1014). Both should be n+nx (as is on line [1029](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/jade-devel/navfn/src/navfn.cpp#L1029)). A pull request with this for indigo and jade would be most welcome.
2. The current x position lies somewhere between stc%nx and (stc%nx)+1. Therefore we want to compute the gradient between stc and stc+1. Similarly in the y direction. Thus we get the four cells which make up the immediate neighborhood of the current position.
3. I think the answer has something to do with the row-order nature of the costmap, but I'm not certain.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2015-11-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1